# Backbone.js DOM isn't ready in render method to apply jquery magic

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to build a todo list with multiple lists. Everything works perfectly fine. The issue comes when I want to use JQuery UI Sortable. 
I'm adding the snippet in my TaskListView in the render function, but I had to wrap it into a setTimeout function so that it waits until the DOM is loaded.

I'm pretty sure there is a better way to do this, but I just couldn't find it yet. Help is appreciated.

```
var TaskView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(task) {
        this.task = task;
    },
    render: function() {
        var completedClass = "completedTask";
        if (this.task.completed == 100) completedClass = "pendingTask";
        var html = ""
        + "<li class='task-<%= task.get('id') %> ' data-id='<%= task.get('id') %>' sortable='true'>"
        + "<div class='float-left'><i class='icon-trash removeTask' data-id='<%= task.get('id') %>'></i></div>"
        + "<div class='float-left'>"
        + "<span class='editTask ' data-type='title' data-id='<%= task.get('id') %>'><%= task.get('title') %></span> "
        + "</div>"
        + "<div class='float-right'>"
        + "<span class='editTask task-responsible label' data-type='responsible' data-id='<%= task.get('id') %>'><%= task.get('responsible') %></span>"
        + "<span class='editTask task-deadline label' data-type='ended' data-id='<%= task.get('id') %>'><%= task.get('ended') %></span>"
        + "<span class='label criticallyLevelToggle editTask <%= criticallyLevelClass %>' data-type='completed' data-id='<%= task.get('id') %>'><%= parseInt(task.get('completed')) %>%</span>"
        + "</div>"
        + "<div class='clear'>&nbsp;</div>"
        +"</li>";

        var template = _.template( html, {task: this.task, criticallyLevelClass:this.task.getCriticallyLevelClass(), completed: completedClass});
        this.$el.html(template);
        return this;
    }
});

var TaskListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(tasks) {
        this.tasks = tasks;
    },
    render: function() {
        var html = ""
        +"<ul class='tasks'>"
        +"<%= tasksli %>"
        +"<li><div class='float-left'><input type='text' placeholder='New task...' class='new-task' name='new-task'/></div><div class='clear'>&nbsp;</div></li>"
        +"</ul>";
        + "";
        var tasksRendered = "";
        if (_.isArray(this.tasks)) {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.tasks.length; i++) {
                var tView = new TaskView(new Task(this.tasks[i]));
                tasksRendered += tView.render().el.innerHTML;
            };
        }
        var template = _.template(html, { tasksli: tasksRendered});
        this.$el.html(template);

        setTimeout(function(){this.$('.tasks').sortable({
            stop: function(e, ui) {
                ui.item.trigger('drop', ui.item.index());
            }
        });}, 500);

        return this;
    }
});
```

Comment: you might want to use `$(document).ready(function() { //your code here });` to solve that problem

Comment: Unrelated hint: Instead of concatenating your HTML inside your JS you can add this to your HTML: <script type="text/template" id="my-template"> [insert html code] </script>. In your javascript use: template:_.template($('#my-template').html())

Comment: Hazaart: Thanks... I will take a look at that. Would make everything a bit more readable ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `setTimeout`, just use `$(function () { })` (or `$(document).ready`) as you would normally to wait for the DOM to be ready.  There is nothing special about these functions, and you can add new callbacks to them at any point. All you have to worry about is maintaining the meaning of `this` in your callback.

```
render: function() {
    var html = ""
    +"<ul class='tasks'>"
    +"<%= tasksli %>"
    +"<li><div class='float-left'><input type='text' placeholder='New task...' class='new-task' name='new-task'/></div><div class='clear'>&nbsp;</div></li>"
    +"</ul>";
    + "";
    var tasksRendered = "";
    if (_.isArray(this.tasks)) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.tasks.length; i++) {
            var tView = new TaskView(new Task(this.tasks[i]));
            tasksRendered += tView.render().el.innerHTML;
        };
    }
    var template = _.template(html, { tasksli: tasksRendered});
    this.$el.html(template);
    var self = this;

    $(function(){
        self.$('.tasks').sortable({
        stop: function(e, ui) {
            ui.item.trigger('drop', ui.item.index());
        }
    })

    return this;
}
```

Alternatively, (and probably more correctly) take steps to make sure that your backbone view isn't having its `render` method called until the DOM is ready.

Comment: @meager: and how would I go about this? e.g. making sure that DOM is ready until the render function is called (-> that's what I'm looking for).

Comment: Somewhere you're instantiating views, or routers, or *something*, which is triggering the rendering of your view. Don't do that, except in a `$(function() { ... })` callback. Possibly it's as simple as moving your `Backbone.history.start()` to within a `$(function () { })`.

Comment: I think the issue is, that the .sortable() function gets called before my little view arrives in the DOM (the DOM as a full is already rendered). Now I don't understand how I could prevent that flow? ... isn't it going to trigger every time my runtime passes this passage?

Comment: I fixed it. The issue was that I wasn't using the views correctly. I rendered the subview to a string and used that in the parent view. Obviously that didn't work. Now I made my views and subview backbone compliant and it's working just fine now.

Comment: Would love to see your fixed code. After reading your comment, I think I may be making the same mistake.