# Backbone cannot use this.el immediately after it is defined

Tags: javascript, variables, backbone.js

I have a question about using variables immediately after they have been declared.

I have always tried to do things like this:

```
var BuzzQuizView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('.buzz-quiz'),
    liveMarked: this.el.data('live-marked'),
    questionTotal: this.el.data('question-count'),
    quizId: this.el.data('quiz-id'),
    ...
```

Or if we take the issue away from Backbone I have always tried things like this:

```
var $answer = $('.answer'),
    $question = $answer.parent().parent();
```

But I always get an error, for the Backbone example it is:

`Cannot read property 'data' of undefined`

and in the case of the variables I get the error:

`$answer is not defined`

Why is this? I just cannot figure it out, why cant I use the variable? As I see it the variable has been declared, the code has executed so the variable should be available.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

**---- EDIT ----**

So I have come that the normal JS example above using `var` does actually work perfectly.

What I was meant to be asking is why the same issue persists in any type of object take the following as an example:

```
var obj = {
    $body: $('body'),
    allDivs: $body.find('allDivs'),
    ...
}
```

Why is $body not available at this point?

Comment: you probably need to wait until the dom has loaded before you excecute your code.  just use $(function () { }) (or $(document).ready) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17087618/backbone-js-dom-isnt-ready-in-render-method-to-apply-jquery-magic

Comment: The DOM is loaded, i load all scripts through require.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`this.el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el) should be specified as jQuery selector **string** or **DOM element**. Not *jQuery object*, as in your code (`$('.buzz-quiz')`).

Also `this.el` is undefined at the moment when you pass options to `Backbone.View` constructor. It is only available since `Backbone.View` is instantiated.

So you have to initialize that properties inside `Backbone.View` constructor:

```
var BuzzQuizView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.buzz-quiz',
    initialize: function() {
        this.liveMarked = this.$el.data('live-marked');
        this.questionTotal = this.$el.data('question-count');
        this.quizId = this.$el.data('quiz-id');
    }
    ...
});
```

Comment: Just curious, why cant el be `$('.buzz-quiz')`? then you wouldn't have to query for it 3 different times? Then wouldnt it need to be `$(this.el).data('live-marked')` if you leave it as a string?

Comment: Hey, thanks for this you have helped me understand how Backbone works but can you please look at the update in my question, I would like to know why this doesn't work in any type of object.

Comment: @Rosenumber14 Just due to the Backbone signature. Read [the docs](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el)

Comment: Oh ok, neat! It caches it for you.

Comment: @lukehillonline I found this (it was kind of hard to find): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173610/can-a-javascript-object-property-refer-to-another-property-of-the-same-object

Comment: @Rosenumber14 thanks for finding that, so as I understand it, `this` is not updated as the code runs through the object, it is only at the closing of the object that `this` is completely updated?

Comment: @lukehillonline Yeah, the object must be fully constructed before it can use its variables.

Comment: @Rosenumber14 brilliant thanks for helping me understand.